# Jinja, templates inheritance and Flask blueprints: how to ectend the parent template from child html if the parent is outside of childs' package

Tags: html, flask, runtime-error, jinja2

I am using Jinja and Flask blueprints. However, I have issues rendering the child templates (albums.html) when I let it inherit from the parent (base.html) and get a TemplateNotFound error.

I tried to use relative paths and absolute paths inside `{% extends 'path' %}` and also googled but didn't find a solution.

My app is structured in this way:

```
flask/
  app.py
  statc/
    templates/
       base.html
  blueprints/
    albums/
       __init__.py
       templates/
          albums.html
       routes.py
```

The `base.html` file is very simple:

```
<!-- language-all: lang-html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>{% block title %}{{ title }}{% endblock%}</title>
    <!-- what shows up on search engine -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        {% block header %}
        <h1>{{header}}</h1>{% endblock%}
    </header>
    <main> <h1> Hello </h1> </main>
    <footer> Some footer </footer>
</body>
```

The child template (`albums.html`) looks like this:

```
{% extends "static/templates/base.html" %} 
{% block title %}{{title}}{% endblock %} 
{% block header %}{{header}} {% endblock %}
```

And the `routes.py` file looks like this:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, abort, url_for
from jinja2.exceptions import TemplateNotFound

album_page = Blueprint('album_page', __name__,
                       template_folder='./templates/albums')
                       
@album_page.route('/albums')
def albums():
    try:
        context = {
            'title': 'Albums',
            'header': 'Albums'
        }
        return render_template('albums.html', **context)
    except TemplateNotFound:
        print('error')
        abort(404)
```

However I get a `TemplateNotFound` error. Is there a way to make  Jinja search in the `static` folder outside of the blueprints' package? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Within a Blueprint, `template_folder` is relative to the Blueprint. So either change

```
template_folder='./templates/albums'
```

to

```
template_folder='templates'
```

or change

```
return render_template('albums.html', **context)
```

to
return render_template('templates/albums.html', **context)

and add an extra `templates` directory, moving `albums.html` into that.

I'd do the former, since the latter clutters things needlessly.

Comment: I changed the code as you suggested, but it did not solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved by moving the `templates` folder from the  `static` folder to the root of the project, and then simply call `{% extends "base.html" %}` inside `albums.html`